# Cannot find what is causing memory leak

Tags: java, android, eclipse, memory-leaks

Maybe this is beginner question, but after many hours of searching, watching videos etc., I cannot find any answer. I am trying to develop my first app with Eclipse Java - ADT and I have started to take care about Logcat and I am seeing often **"dalvikvm - GC_CONCURENT and GC__FOR_ALLOC"** with pause 50ms+, I have searched and watched some videos and I finally try to analyse my app by Eclipse Memory Analyse Tool, I run the app on mobile device - go to DDMS, make `.hprof` file and I have found that I have around 30MB+ leak, so I tried to find where it is and I finally realized that even if I make new blank app "Hello World" and run analyzer, there is still 21MB leak - so there have to be something I dont understand.

This is my first post so I cannot post images so I give you just a link to image from Eclipse Memory Analyzer. Thanks in advance for answer.

[image]

Comment: Could you add some information about the way you build your application?  Could you give a brief explanation of the deliverable you have generated (its structure, libraries that you have included, resources, etc.)?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just started "eclipse.exe" - > "New Android Application" - > it created new project with first activity and xml "Hello World", I didnt change anything and just run application and put results to analyzer and it show me this graph. I have tried it on other (older) version of Android device and leak was lower, but it is still too much for nearly empty application. There have to be be something - maybe it loads some default templates and I should delete it when I start new project. Now I only edit src folder, res folder and AndroidManifest.xml - anything else is default.

Comment: Just to make it sure, try to export it with eclipse to whatever format it uses and have a look at the resources and libraries included with the empty application

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me, I exported and there is no any other res and libs, but default. I tried to investigate more and the most of the leaks are preloaded bitmaps. For example one with size 2.5MB, when I tried to save .data and open in GIMP, it is just gradient bitmap. I have full HD device so maybe thats why bitmaps are so big, but still 20MB seems too large - I dont even use any of them.

Comment: That was the reason I asked about the packaging of your deliverable, where do those bitmaps come from?  Are they loaded by default from some other source or are they included into your application by some mean?